# XMLsearch equivalent for PHP

Tags: php

I am new to the PHP world and I have an XML file that looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?> 
<outageResponse>
  <stormFlag>C</stormFlag> 
  <timeStamp>2015-06-22T16:10:32</timeStamp> 
  <stormCount /> 
  <outage job="239369" circ="0587" start="2015-06-22T06:12:00" ert="2015-06-22T19:00:00" ertty="F" cau="We have determined that a combination of factors has caused a problem." cust="0000019" comm="605" x="-117.28778580262241" y="33.123002776709676" district="NC" substation="XYZ" device="DBE.279317" calltype="OUT" damage="" /> 
  <outage job="239454" circ="0587" start="2015-06-22T06:01:44" ert="2015-06-22T19:00:00" ertty="F" cau="We have determined that a combination of factors has caused a problem." cust="0000016" comm="605" x="-117.28778580262241" y="33.123002776709676" district="NC" substation="ABC" device="LBE.283559" calltype="OUT" damage="" /> 
  <outage job="239413" circ="220" start="2015-06-22T09:03:00" ert="2015-06-22T16:30:00" ertty="F" cau="Wprking on it." cust="0000007" comm="386" x="-116.67117489543362" y="33.110485186359256" district="RA" substation="DEF" device="<inline_jumper.4356>" calltype="PLAN" damage="" switchplan="71474" />
</outageResponse>
```

So, In ColdFusion, I would do the following:

```
<cfset MyXMLDoc = XMLParse(XMLURL)>
<cfset MyOutages = xmlSearch(MyXMLDoc,'/outageResponse/outage')>
<cfloop from="1" to="#arraylen(MyOutages)#" index="i">
  <cfset MyJob = MyOutages[i].XmlAttributes["job"]>
  <cfset MyCircuit = MyOutages[i].XmlAttributes["circ"]>
</cfloop>
```

I am unable to find examples of how I would do this in PHP.
There are many simple examples out there, but nothing for the above XML file.

I can figure out how to pull the values of the attributes as such:

```
echo "Value of job attribute in the first outage array: " . (string)$MyXMLDoc->outage[0]->attributes()->job;
```

However, I haven't been able to figure out how many arrays of outage I have in the XML file since each time I get the XML file, there may be different number of outages or none at all.

Comment: You could use [xpath](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php). It's the first result from google for "php xmlSearch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the problem is that the XML is invalid. Proper XML must be escaped for "<" and "&", [except in certain contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#syntax). So, if you take out the "<>" (or better yet, convert them to `&lt;` and `&gt;` inside the quotes on line 8 of the XML, we can use SimpleXML to parse this.

```
$filedata = 'Your XML from a file, etc.';
$xmlData = new SimpleXMLElement($fileData);

echo "Children: " . $xmlData->count() . "\n";
$outageChildren = 0;
foreach ($xmlData as $outage) {
    if (empty($outage)) continue;  // Because of mixed list
    $outageChildren++;
    $job = $outage['job'];
    $circuit = $outage['circ'];

    echo "Value of job attributes '$job' and circuit '$circuit'\n";
}
echo "Total 'outage' children: $outageChildren\n";
```

Output:

```
Children: 6
Value of job attributes '239369' and circuit '0587'
Value of job attributes '239454' and circuit '0587'
Value of job attributes '239413' and circuit '220'
Total 'outage' children: 3
```

It is more typical in XML to put a list (or array) of items in their own container, like so:

```
<outageResponse>
  <stormFlag>C</stormFlag> 
  <timeStamp>2015-06-22T16:10:32</timeStamp> 
  <stormCount /> 
  <outages>
    <outage job="239369" circ="0587" start="2015-06-22T06:12:00" ert="2015-06-22T19:00:00" ertty="F" cau="We have determined that a combination of factors has caused a problem." cust="0000019" comm="605" x="-117.28778580262241" y="33.123002776709676" district="NC" substation="XYZ" device="DBE.279317" calltype="OUT" damage="" /> 
    <outage job="239454" circ="0587" start="2015-06-22T06:01:44" ert="2015-06-22T19:00:00" ertty="F" cau="We have determined that a combination of factors has caused a problem." cust="0000016" comm="605" x="-117.28778580262241" y="33.123002776709676" district="NC" substation="ABC" device="LBE.283559" calltype="OUT" damage="" /> 
    <outage job="239413" circ="220" start="2015-06-22T09:03:00" ert="2015-06-22T16:30:00" ertty="F" cau="Wprking on it." cust="0000007" comm="386" x="-116.67117489543362" y="33.110485186359256" district="RA" substation="DEF" device="<inline_jumper.4356>" calltype="PLAN" damage="" switchplan="71474" />
  </outages>
</outageResponse>
```

It isn't required, but it's helpful. Assuming you can't change the input format, you'll need to keep the `if`...`continue` on the first line of the foreach loop to skip entries that are not an "outage". Note that SimpleXML actually uses the name of the variable in the `foreach` (`$outage`) to determine which elements to read in. That's a little strange, but it's why the "stormFlag", "timeStamp" and "stormCount" elements are not counted (or more specifically are skipped) by our `foreach` loop.

Note: As you alluded to in your question, remember to cast these values with `(string)` before using them as a string since you will sometimes get weird results when the rest of your code expects it to be a string and it isn't quite (it's still a member of `SimpleXMLElement`).